# Why is my class-based view only working with GET?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I wanted to ask a question, but I kind of found an answer myself and wanted to share it here. Perhaps someone can even tell me what was happening.

I created an UpdateView subclass like several times before. But when I got to the page via a button that was part of method=post form I only got an empty form. Was driving me mad. In the end, I found just incidentally that when I entered the URL again in the address bar the values were received from the database. I changed the form with the button from post to get and when I now click it to go to the UpdateView page, it works. But to be honest, I do not know why. CVBs are still mysterious for me ;)

Comment: A GET request is not supposed to create/update/delete data from the database. GET requests are supposed to have *no* side-effects.

Comment: Dear Willem, thanks. But could you tell me why that is?

Comment: because that is how it was designed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods): "*the GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using **GET should only retrieve data and should have no other effect**. (This is also true of some other HTTP methods.)[1] The W3C has published guidance principles on this distinction, saying, "Web application design should be informed by the above principles, but also by the relevant limitations."[24].*"

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would have some security reasons.

Answer (score -1):

You will make a great app, you are close, here is an example below, you need to define POST and GET methods, by default class-based views use the GET function

```
class profile(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        profile = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        return Response()

    def post(self, request):
        mydata = request.POST
        return redirect('/accounts/profile/')
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to declare his in my views.py? And how do I access mydata then? For example, if I had request.POST['foo'], would I then use mydata['foo']?